# Include header outside of namespace

Tags: c++

I have few complicated header files which I am enclosing inside namespace. In the middle of the header file some headers are included. Is there an easy way to include that included header in global scope? i.e. in the code below, can I indicate someheader to be included in global namespace?

```
#pragma once

namespace foo
{
    // lots of code; 
    // depending on lots of conditions defined above
    #define bar

#ifdef bar
    #include <someheader> // would be available only when bar is set/ 
#endif

//
```

Comment: Close `namespace foo` before the `#include` and reopen it afterwards?  IIRC, you can add to namespaces, unlike classes.  (You have to be able to extend namespaces for the `std` namespace to be workable.) . But you probably want to look at how you've modularized your code.  It sounds very messy.

Comment: I have to question why this code is inside a namespace in the first place. `#define`, `#ifdef` etc. don't care in the slightest about namespaces, so you could do all that preprocessor fun _outside_ of `foo` and not worry about the namespace issue at all.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler - I was trying to avoid that; slightly longer effort.
you are right, but that #define depends on other #defines and that is spread out across files, and collecting that code all outside using namespace also required careful/longer coding.

Answer (score -3):

Yes, that would be very much possible, although you then have to check whether `#define bar` is defined whenever you use bits of code from that header file. I also recommend that you close the namespace before including the header.

Comment: When someone asks "can I do X", they aren't looking for a literal yes/no answer.